# Table values moved after being added to old QGIS version: behaves normally on current version

Tags: excel, vector, import, qgis

I am teaching a man the basics of QGis for a project he needs to do at his work. He has very little computer knowledge and would like to standardise the work as much as possible (specific workarounds would complicate it too much for him). His QGis version is 3.16 "Hannover" and as this is a work laptop he does not have permission to download a newer version.

We have been having problem with one specific table. The first few rows are below, written exactly as they are originally.

```
Baum-Nr.   Baumart   BHD   Alter   Y           X      Biotopbaum   Klassifizierung   Bemerkungen
1           Buche    86     120   49.1356   11.0488       A            Altbaum       Freistellen !!!
2           Kiefer   45     100   49.13561  11.04883   Hlb,Bs,Th     Höhlenbaum
3           Kiefer   32     100   49.13571  11.04579   Hlb,Sw,Th     Höhlenbaum
4           Kiefer   74     120   49.13513  11.0495       A            Altbaum
```

After adding it from Excel to QGis through "add vector layer", the header "Klassifizierung" becomes one of the coordinates and I believe one of the columns are switched (unfortunately, I can't remember specifics. This is a small side job and I haven't had time to look into it for days. I should have taken a photo, but this isn't possible anymore). We have attempted to copy the column into a new Excel document and transferring it to QGis again, and this time the headers were shoved one cell to the right such that "Y" was placed over "X" and "Biotopbaum" over "Klassifizierung", for example.

I could not find a way to fix the import problem in his laptop. He e-mailed me the problematic table and I opened it successfully in my QGis 3.26 "Buenos Aires".

I believe this may be a problem with his QGis version, but it is curious that we only encountered it with this one table. All other tables we have worked with have the same headers and the same kind of data on their respective rows.

Is this a known problem, or have other people faced similar situations? Could someone explain what could be causing it? Would there be a way to fix it such that we can successfully import the table without having to edit it in QGis? This is not a solution the man would accept.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the commas in the Biotopbaum field or replace them with a less common delimiter.  In fact, remove all punctionation (e.g., Baum-Nr. >> remove the period ".").

Also save the table into a csv format and try to import.

Comment: Old question but I forgot to mark as solved. Importing into csv solved it. Thank you